# Continued Fraction of Random Variables

Tags: pr.probability, continued-fractions

So this is my first post in mathoverflow. I posted this problem in [**Mathstack**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2344894/continued-fraction-and-random-variable), an I've also
put a bounty on it, but did not get any response. If anyone can at least point out a reference on this problem, I will be grateful.

> Let $X_1,X_2,\dots$ be independent random variables such that $P(X_i=1)=p=1-
>  P(X_i=\epsilon_i)$, for some $0<\epsilon_i<1$, and let
>
> $$Y=X_1+\frac{X_1}{X_2+\frac{X_2}{X_3+\frac{X_3}{X_4+\dots}}} \, .$$

1. **What is the distribution of $Y$?**
2. **What is the characteristic  function of $Y$?**

We can think of **less complicated** version:

Let $X_1,X_2,\dots$ be i.i.d. random variables such that $P(X_1=1)=p=1-P(X_1=\epsilon)$ for some $0<\epsilon <1$

$$Y=X_1+\frac{X_1}{X_2+\frac{X_2}{X_3+\frac{X_3}{X_4+\dots}}}$$

Here we can write: $Y=Y_1$, $Y_1=X_1(1+\frac{1}{Y_2})$, $Y_2=X_2(1+\frac{1}{Y_3})$ and so on. It can be easily seen that $Y_i$'s are identical but not independent. So, I think that first we should answer questions **1** and **2** for this simpler case.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker should I delete this post or I delete mathstack post?

Comment: it's OK, but referencing both posts is good practice to avoid duplication of efforts.

Comment: I added the link of mathstack post in this post.

Answer (score 6):

A general approach to problems of this type, worked out for a slightly different continued fraction, 
$$Y_n=X_n+1/X_{n-1},$$
is described in [Random Continued Fractions: A Markov Chain Approach](https://www.jstor.org/stable/25055738?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) (2004).

A closed-form answer follows if the $X_n$'s have a Gamma distribution, $$P(X)\propto X^{\lambda-1}e^{-aX},\;\; X> 0,$$ 
when the $n\rightarrow\infty$ limit of $Y_n$ tends to the distribution $$P(Y)\propto Y^{\lambda-1}\exp[-a(Y+1/Y)],\;\; Y>0.$$ 
This result goes back to [A characterization of the generalized inverse Gaussian distribution by continued fractions](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00534200?LI=true) (1983). A Bernoulli distribution for the $X_n$'s gives a more complicated answer for $P(Y)$.

Comment: Sir, a partial solution has been done @Steven Stadnicki in Mathstack, you may see that. Link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2344894/continued-fraction-and-random-variable